# Bigtable is used even in other search engines

Tags: bigtable

Is the Bigtable implemented only in Google or, even other search engines implement the same file structure?

Answer (score 1):

It's basically a Google technology used internally. If others have implemented something like it, they've done so from a client library perspective, and likely changed the name.

> Many projects at Google store data in Bigtable, including web
>   indexing, Google Earth, and Google Finance. These applications place
>   very different demands on Bigtable, both in terms of data size (from
>   URLs to web pages to satellite imagery) and latency requirements (from
>   backend bulk processing to real-time data serving). Despite these
>   varied demands, Bigtable has successfully provided a flexible,
>   high-performance solution for all of these Google products.

You might like the section on Wikipedia about [similar software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable#Other_similar_software).

Answer (score 0):

Bigtable pioneered the NoSQL data storage approach. It is likely that other search engines use similar techniques at some point in their evolution and depending on their scale requirements as NoSQL can be a good fit for some of these cases.

For example, Elasticsearch is a NoSQL database, more-or-less: 
https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-as-nosql

Relatedly, here's a post from Microsoft's Bing team about their storage requirements and architecture:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/blog/evolution-bings-objectstore/